# How to use a clock within a while loop

Tags: c++, timer, sfml, clock, pause

i'm coding a game and I've been trying to implement a pause game functionality where when the user presses R the game will pause, and after x time when R is pressed again, the game will resume. I have gotten this to work when user presses R, and when any other key such as M is pressed the game will resume as normal. However, when I assign R to both pause and unpause events, the initial R is detected for both pause and unpause, and the game pauses for a fraction of a second and resumes. I've tried implementing timers and counters inside my pause loop but to no avail. what I really want to do is make it so that the user must wait x amount of time before R is pressed again, this will fix the problem, but I can't get `clock.getElapsedTime` to work within the loop for some reason. Why is this? here's my current code:

```
case sf::Keyboard::R:
        pause = true;   
        break;


//pause game
        clock1.restart();
        while (pause)
        {               
            //cout << clock1.getElapsedTime.asSeconds();

            //if (clock1.getElapsedTime.asSeconds() > 1.0)
            //{
                if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::R))
                    pause = false;
            //}
        }
```

Comment: What does the commented line print?

Comment: it comes up with an error and doesn't print anything if you're referring to the cout statement

Comment: 1>c:\sfml-2.3.2\sfml\main.cpp(26852): error C2228: left of '.asSeconds' must have class/struct/union
1>c:\sfml-2.3.2\sfml\main.cpp(26854): error C2228: left of '.asSeconds' must have class/struct/union

Comment: Is that because you forgot to put parentheses after asSeconds?

Comment: am I missing parentheses in the sample code?

Comment: Is `clock1.asSeconds` a variable, or a function?

Comment: it's a class function that comes with SFML I believe, clock1 is a clock object and asSeconds and getElapsedTime are member functions of clock1

Comment: So if it's a function, presumably you want to call it? With `()`?

Comment: ah, Indeed adding parentheses after getElapsedTime stops the error from popping up, it still doesn't behave as intended though, it unpauses and then pauses again almost immediately

Comment: i'm not able to break out of the while loop after setting pause to false, why is this and how can it be fixed?

Comment: nevermind I got it all working perfectly, if you answer the question i'll choose you as best answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing **sf::sleep(sf::seconds(0.1));** BEFORE your while loop. I had the same problem. Somehow if I would read the value of isKeyPressed() for the same letter consequently it would not change at the time I read it the second time and would assume it's still pressed. Placing a little pause there solved my problem, so try if it does solve it in your case.

*Please* tell me if it works, I am interested

Comment: I already got it working and i've heard that putting sleep in a game slows it down but thx for the response! I'll choose you as best answer

Comment: Since that sleep doesn't happen too often, it doesn't slow it down much, since the program is waiting for the human's response anyway, and it doesn't usually come that quickly.

Comment: Can you share your way of fixing it?